# how to set auto size to textarea in appcelerator when it was added with tableview row?

Tags: ios, textarea, tableview, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I am new to appcelerator. I am developing an ios app in that i have a requirement to provide a autosize to text area.while i am adding textarea to tableview row it will not allow me to enter text into textArea .Thanks in advance..

index.xml

```
<TableViewRow id="textRow" width="100%" height="12%">
                <View id="textView" >
                <Label id="text" text="Text" left="4%" top="12%" color="#a8a8a8" />
                <TextArea id="textArea" width="65%" right="2%" textAlign="right"  returnKeyType="Titanium.UI.RETURNKEY_DONE" top="12%"/>
                </View>
                </TableViewRow>
```

Comment: Could explain how "i have a requirement to provide a autosize to text area" and "it will not allow me to enter text into textArea" is related? Could it be that because of using Ti.UI.SIZE (for height?) it is not showing at all? Try to debug by setting a background color on the text area

Comment: Thank you for giving reply. In above I mentioned code is working fine with static tableview row size 12% but i want fix the tableview row size depends on size of textarea. let me know  how can i achieve it.

Comment: Just set `TableViewRow`'s height to `Ti.UI.SIZE`?

Comment: Thank you for giving reply .If i set Ti.UI.SIZE to TableVIewRow it's automatically take more than 70% empty space it's not my requirement.In my window i have four TableViewRow's which has 4 textArea.If i mentioned Ti.UI.SIZE every row occupies more than 70% of space.But I want initially every TableViewRow maintain 10 to 12 % of height.while editing textArea depends on textSize it will auto increase

Comment: If i use below code textarea not allow me to edit .                     <TableViewRow id="textRow" width="100%" height="Ti.UI.SIZE">
               
                <Label id="text" text="Text" left="4%" color="#a8a8a8" />
                <TextArea id="textArea" width="65%" right="2%" textAlign="right"  returnKeyType="Titanium.UI.RETURNKEY_DONE" />
                </TableViewRow>